# Determine the time period of when my app was purchased

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

Is there a way (in code) that you can give an app different features based on when it was purchased??

I have people who have bought my app for a different price and some had it free during a promotion. 
It would be nice to give a little thank you with an extra feature in my app for the ones who paid for it.

Is that in anyway possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having it in place beforehand, you won't ever know about the past, but nothing prevents you from putting the timestamp of when a user first opened your app into e.g. the user settings. Something like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
    setObject:[NSDate date] 
       forKey:@"install_date"];
```

which you could then use to decide how to "treat" (I guess) the user. The one catch is that if a user ever deletes the app and then reinstalls it, their early adopter bonus or whatever will be lost. The only other option you have is to send the device ID to a dedicated server somewhere, e.g. a PHP script with a simple MySQL db where device id's are stored along with dates. You could then do something like

```
NSDate *purchaseDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
    objectForKey:@"purchase_date"];
if (nil == purchaseDate) {
    // we need to get the date for this user from the server, or
    // we need to register the user as it's the first time
} else {
    // we know when this user installed the app, and they did so 
    // (approximately) at the purchaseDate time.
}
```

Date format issues aside, the above should be pretty straightforward, but as said, does require a server somewhere (which can be a slow mo because the above only happens on first install and reinstalls).

Edit: you can use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` (deprecated as of iOS 5) or `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]` (new as of iOS 6.. lol) to get the device ID.

Comment: Thanks for that - it makes sense in regards to the install basis. This was the better answer in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage it by code officially Apple don't provide any code for that. But if in case you need any kind of analysis of app. Like , which part of app was used by user, which part makes crash of app, something kind of feature you can try this [Flurry Analytics](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html) for it .

Comment: Thanks I will look into that - seems simple enough:-)

Comment: Analytics software doesn't help you to detect when an actual instance of an app on a device was purchased!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect from within your app when an app has been purchased. You could add detection of when it was installed, but that could have happened at any later time, even multiple times.